# Opening Visual Studio 2015 files with Visual Studio 2019 Commun

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019, ssrs-subscription

Hi I am attempting to open my files created in Visual Studion 2015 in Visual Studion Community Edition 2019. It tells me it can't find the application despite that I have installed any relevant extension like Reporting Services etc. Does anyone else have a similar problems opening old reports in Visual Studio 2019?

Tried downloading datatools, tried upgrading the reporting extensions nothing worked.

Application not found

Comment: You'll have to copy/paste the content of the project file into your question to get an accurate guess.

Comment: Not sure I understand this. I am have old reports that I have created in visual studio 2015 . I now have visual studio 2019 and is no longer able to open  the reports or do some work with them in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Ask a colleague to help you identify the specific report designer tool that you used.  There are far too many of them in common use and without the project file we can't see anything.  If you have absolutely no idea then it is possibly useful to guess at [this add-on](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001).  It used to be included in older VS versions but Microsoft wants to retire it.  Just a guess.